# undefined reference to `PyInit_QtGui'

Tags: makefile, python-3.4, ubuntu-14.04, pyqt5

i tried to compile `pyqt` script with `pyqtdeploy` tool,
running `qmake main.pro` success, but **`make`** command contain following error:

```
main.o:(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `PyInit_QtWidgets'
main.o:(.data.rel+0x18): undefined reference to `PyInit_QtGui'
main.o:(.data.rel+0x28): undefined reference to `PyInit_QtCore'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

google can't helped me.
please explain how to solve this error.
**development informations:**
`PyQt5` - `Python3.4` - `ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: Have you installed the `python3-pyqt5` package with `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`?

Comment: @ldrumm,yes,off course :)

Comment: Make sure the interpreter you give pyqtdeploy is the one with pyqt5 installed. Does the application you deploy use the same python installation as the one used to run pyqtdeploy? (if not, that could be a source of error)

Comment: @Pedru,pyqtdeploy installed from `pip3` and yes,`pyqtdeploy` used `python3`,pyqtdeploy generate `makeFile`,but `makeFile` contain reference error for `qtwidget`(i fixed it manually),but unable to fix above errors.

Comment: Did you compile sip and pyqt statically and are they part of the ld command (as a .a library)?  Shouldn't PyInit_QtCore be defined in one of the pyqt libraries.  You could use 'nm' to check.